# Ping Federate : Ruby Integration Kit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-sign-on, integration, pingfederate

I am currently using PingFederate with following description :

```
Version: 7.1.3.1
Protocol Support: SAML 2.0, WS-Federation, SAML 1.1, SAML 1.0, WS-Trust, OAuth 2.0
```

And I have an IdP application built on Java and an SP application built on Ruby on Rails.

And , I am using PIngFederate with SSO profile as :

```
Protocol : SAML 2.0
Adapter : OpenToken
Connection Option : Browser SSO
Connection Type :  Browser SSO Profiles     Protocol   SAML 2.0
```

Problem

For JAVA , PingFederate has provided the **pf-Java-integration-kit** with **open-token-adapter**, and the rest of implementation are well documented.

But however for ROR, PingFederate doesn't seem to provide the integration kit as listed in their [Download page](https://www.pingidentity.com/en/products/downloads.html)

Question

1. Is there a integration Kit for ROR ?
2. I seem to have found lots of forum implicating the fact, but i don't
   know if it does exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've already deduced, there's no integration kit specific for RoR, but you could use the [Agentless Integration Kit](http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/AIK12/Agentless+Integration+Kit), which is language-agnostic.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out on this. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is an Open Source RoR kit for OpenToken that was written by a Ping customer a few years ago. I did a quick search and found a link to the source -- https://github.com/socialcast/opentoken.

Or as Mehmet mentioned you could us the [Agentless Kit](http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/AIK12/Agentless+Integration+Kit) which is maintained and officially supported by Ping Identity.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out on this.